# Overload std::unique_ptr deleter method using std::enable_if

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, unique-ptr, sfinae

I am trying to write a deleter for my `std::unique_ptr`, and I would like to overload the method for deletion. Here is what I tried, but the compiler complains about the use of `std::enable_if_t`. Code is compiled using `-std=c++20` flag.

```
template <class T>
class custom_deleter
{
public:
    template <class U, std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_v<T>, bool> = true>
    void operator()(U* ptr) { std::cout << "array"; }

    template <class U, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_array_v<T>, bool> = true>
    void operator()(U* ptr) { std::cout << "non-array"; }
};
```

Here's the compiler error:

```
main.cpp:17:10: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, bool>'
   17 |     void operator()(U* ptr) { std::cout << "non-array"; }
      |          ^~~~~~~~
```

I don't understand the issue. At first, I thought I was missing an included or compile flag for `std::enable_if_t` to be available, but its not the problem here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I believe the `enable_if_t` condition has to depend on `U` (or on some template parameter of the `operator()`). Alternatively, you can use `requires` from C++20.

Comment: Thank you, just realizing that now. Since I have access to C++20, using `if constexpr` makes it even more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SFINAE required a template parameter of the function to be depended on. That means the `std::enable_if_t` can only be applied for the `U` not for the class template `T`. Therefore, you need to include the template parameter `T` in your  `operator()`s somehow (like `class U = T`) or just [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) the  `operator()` as you are anyway have acces to [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20):

```
template <class T>
class custom_deleter
{
public:
    template <class U = T>
    void operator()(U* ptr)
    {         
        if constexpr(std::is_array_v<U>)  std::cout << "array"; 
        else if constexpr(!std::is_array_v<U>)  std::cout << "non-array";
    }
};

int main()
{
    custom_deleter<int[2]> arrDel;
    custom_deleter<std::string> strDel;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::is_array/_v` does not recognize `std::array` as an array (see [this example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_array)). You need to use either `custom_deleter<int[]>` or `custom_deleter<int[2]>` instead.

Comment: _SFINAE required a template parameter of the function to be depended on._ <- That is the part I was not aware of, and responsible for my issue. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

SFINAE kicks in when choosing what function to call, but your condition depends on `T` only not on `U`. Actually not sure if this is the right explanation, sfinae makes me dizzy :P. As you are using C++20 I would suggest `constexpr if` rather than SFINAE. Anyhow, this compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


template <class T>
class custom_deleter
{
public:
    template <class U,class W=T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_array_v<W>, bool> = true>
    void operator()(U* ptr) { std::cout << "non-array"; }

    template <class U,class W=T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_v<W>, bool> = true>
    void operator()(U* ptr) { std::cout << "array"; }

};


int main(){
    custom_deleter<int> p{};
    p("asd");
}
```

On a second thought.. why is there `U` and `T` ? Don't you want a `custom_deleter<T>` to delete `T`s? I suppose you actually want this:

```
template <class T>
class custom_deleter
{
public:
    template <class U=T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_array_v<U>, bool> = true>
    void operator()(U* ptr) { std::cout << "non-array"; }

    template <class U=T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_array_v<U>, bool> = true>
    void operator()(U* ptr) { std::cout << "array"; }

};


int main(){
    custom_deleter<int> p{};
}
```

Comment: I stripped a lot of the original code in my example to make it easier to read, but essentially, the deleter is storing `T` for some other purpose, hence why I end up with both `T` and `U`.